# Create a `CheckConstraint` within a `UniqueConstraint`

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Before creating a new record I want to check a condition that the combination of  `native_linux_user` and `is_active` is unique but `is_active` must be `True`.  Multiple `native_linux_user` with `is_active=False` may exist, but only one `native_linux_user` with `is_active=True` can exist.

I tried to use a `CheckConstraint` within a `UniqueConstraint` like this, but it didn't work.  How do I make this type of constraint?

```
 __table_args__ = (
     UniqueConstraint(
         'native_linux_user',
         CheckConstraint('is_active=True', name='active_check'),
         name='_username_uniqueness'
     ),
 )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From SQL side you can create partial `UNIQUE` index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_unique_native_linux_user_is_active
    ON table (native_linux_user) WHERE is_active=True;
```

And SQLAlchemy model with corresponding `Index`:

```
class Foo(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    native_linux_user = Column(String, nullable=False)
    is_active = Column(Boolean)

    __table_args__ = (
        Index('idx_unique_native_linux_user_is_active', native_linux_user,
            unique=True,
            postgresql_where=(is_active==True),
        ),
    )
```

Comment: What would be the syntax if I am using MySQL as Database ?

Comment: @Nagri - no idea, but I assume it doesn't actually support this feature. (And it's probably the same for its forks: Drizzle, MariaDB, Percona Server and WebScaleSQL)